# How to populate category table that is linked with product table in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have two mysql tables namely category and products.

I have created add.blade.php and adding new products are working well. But I am facing difficulty in editing category name and listing the products with category name. and I do not know which model relationship to use as editing involves in one to one and listing involves in one to many. 
[category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCbxJ.png)

[products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxFgm.png)

[product model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwkjL.png)

[category model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nziqX.png)

[controller edit function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRXsQ.png)

[controller index(listing) function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXtam.png)

Comment: please add `category` and `products` table schema and your code to question.

Comment: you mean i should add schema in my models?

Answer (score 1):

Your products belong to a category so you need a category_id column on your products table.

The relationships would be as simple as

Product.php

```
 public function category()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
 }
```

Category.php

```
 public function products()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
 }
```

This is real basic laravel, you should read the documentation and stop asking questions like this on here